# Binding a silder control to a RotateTransform at runtime in Silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, binding

I know you can do this dynamically in XAML, but how can you do this in code?

I have a rectangle that is drawn by the user, and I want to attach a slider to the rotatetransform, via code.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the anser Vorrtex gave, by loading in XAML at run time, however Silverlight 4.0 added the ability to bind to a dependency objects, so now you can bind
to things like transforms which inherit from Dependency Object. Using the `BindingOperations` class, you can pass in the DependancyObject, the Property you want to bind, and the binding expression.

```
//w is a UIElement
//rot is a rotate transform

w.RenderTransform = rot;

Binding b = new Binding("Value") { Source = RotationSlider };
BindingOperations.SetBinding(rot, RotateTransform.AngleProperty, b);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's strange, that a `Transform` class doesn't have a method `SetBinding()`.
Here is workaround to this problem:

```
var rect = new Rectangle { Width = 100, Height = 60, Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0)) };

var t = 
    XamlReader.Load("<RotateTransform xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' "+
            "Angle='{Binding Value, ElementName=slider1}'/>") as RotateTransform;
rect.RenderTransform = t;
```